# What's the adverb to unencrypted?

Tags: vocabulary, adverbs

"This data must always be stored securely and never ***unencryptedly***, i.e. never store this data in an unencrypted fashion"?

Is there an adverb for unencrypted?

Answer (score 2):

Since ***unencryptedly*** (and non-negated ***encryptedly***) are not idiomatically acceptable "derived adverbial forms", you need to use a ***preposition-based*** form...

> *It must be stored securely and never [stored] **without** [using] **encryption***.

Answer (score 1):

"Unencrypted" is not a verb, it is an adjective - it is modifying the noun "data".

*The unencrypted data.*

The verb form is "to encrypt", for which the preferred antonym is "decrypt" rather than "unencrypt".

So a better way to say this sentence would be:

*This data must always be stored securely, never unencrypted.*

although stylistically I don't like the double negative of "never unencrypted", it is still correct.

Comment: Well, my thought process was that in order to be able to decrypt something, it had to be encrypted first. Which is not the same as something that was never encrypted in the first place. And then, I am wondering - am I not describing how the data is stored (and thus need an adverb) instead if how the data is (adjective)?

Comment: A couple of synonyms for "unencrypted' are "plaintext" and "clear text". For how it is stored, you might use the phrase "as/in clear text".